# Implementing a pure virtual function Change parameter from void* to specific type pointer

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pure-virtual

I have a base Class that implements all the mundane stuff with creating a server which spawns a thread, listens on a queue and processes the received messages.
Those messages are then given to a pure virtual function:

`void ProcMsg(void* msg) = 0;`

In the implementation of the derived Class when implementing the `ProcMsg` I would like to change the `void* msg` to a pointer to as specific message structure definition `MyMsgType* msg`.  Is there a language construct that would allow me to do that or is the only way to re-cast the `void*` to `MyMsgType*` inside of the `ProcMsg` implementation.
The only thing I found is Templates, but I was hoping there would be a simpler way.

Comment: Yes, templates. Sounds like CRTP can assist here

Comment: You can declare `class MyMsgType;` (or a base class of it) before this virtual function's class and you don't need to use void* .

Comment: As I can't catch the real use case, I would expect that having a virtual function AND templates will never work. It looks more like on overload of all types... but I am not sure what you really want to design. In such cases `std::variant` can help also... It would be necessary that you show us what you want to do in a minimal example!

Comment: Why not templates? Seems like that's what you need if you want low overhead.

Comment: `void ProcMsg(void* msg) = 0;` -- Once the parameter is `void *`, you've lost all information as to what `msg` actually points to.

Comment: Maybe you're a bit unfamiliar with templates, but they are not really very difficult and very very useful. This online example may give you some ideas : https://onlinegdb.com/Ka1k-KxHC

Comment: Do you have one or several derived classes? Would they all use the same MyMsgType? Do you use inheritance for a) automatically adding a basic implementation into your derived classes b) Having a standard interface to the outside world c) storing different derived classes which run at the same time together (e.g. in a vector). Depending on your answers, the direction to go is totally different.

Comment: The base class (pure virtual is the framework) is used to do all of the mundane stuff of messaging, setting up threads and so on.  The derived classes constitute different kinds of servers, but all having the same basic model.  Receive a specific type message from a queue, process it and return results to another queue, or file or database.  The point is that the request messages have different structures, so it would be nice to have them delivered to the processing method with the correct structure type instead of just a void pointer.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you want to use the ProcMsg as virtual function instead of having an individually named or overloaded function for each of the derived classes? Is the msg type also unknown at the caller, when it calls ProcMsg? Is ProcMsg called by the base class or by some other code? If it is the base class erasing the msg type, CRTP could be the answer as @Amir Kirsh mentioned.

Comment: The ProcMsg is called by the base class, which is not concerned with its structure as it is only responsible for delivery of a block of bytes, the derived servers need to know the structure of that block of data, hence they need a specific structure pointer.  I was just trying to avoid using a cast on the pointer passed in to the ProcMsg everywhere where it is referenced, as it makes the code look messy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `void *` for any other reason beyond interfacing with some ancient C library, you probably want to rethink your architecture.

I would create a base class for all the messages that be passed and then have a virtual method on those called `process` or something like that. If that turns things around too much, then you might have to have a messageType field and query it, then do some typecasting.